# UITableView SDK add array

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

What I'm trying to do is an app that lets you type in a task to a field, Press insert and see it in the table below it. I have my table (`*table`), my field (`*taskField`), My button (`*insert`) and my array (`*tasks`). I run the app, type something in and press insert but nothing shows up in the table. I also believe i have all my "IB" stuff set up right.

here is my code:

```
NSString *docPath()
{
NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                                        YES);
return [[pathList objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.td" ];
}

#import "CookViewController.h"

@interface CookViewController ()

@end

@implementation CookViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)addRec:(id)sender
{

NSString *t=[taskField text];

if ([t isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return;
}

[tasks addObject:t];
[table reloadData];
[taskField setText:@""];
[taskField resignFirstResponder];
[tasks writeToFile:docPath()
        atomically:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { 
    [tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray     arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; } 

}


#pragma mark - Table View management

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

UITableViewCell *c= [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (!c) {
    c= [[ UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

NSString *item = [tasks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[[c textLabel] setText:item];

return c;

} 

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IB Checklist: 
Right click the table view and see the delegates and reference outlets:

1. `datasource` points to your `ViewController`
2. `delegate` points to your `ViewController`
3. Referencing outlet is correctly defined and the variable in the `ViewController` header has a small blackened O next to it to show an outlet.

To set the `datasource` and `delegate`, press the CTRL button and drag it to your ViewController.

Your ViewController has UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in its header file in the ViewController.:

`@interface ViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Note: By ViewController I mean CookViewController in your case.

EDIT: Change this function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  table.delegate = self;
  table.dataSource = self;
}
```

--V

Comment: my datasource and delegate are not pointing to anything as far as I can Tell (The o's are empty). My reference outlet is pointing to addRec and has a black o. I dont see anything like UITableViewDataSource in my files. Do I need to change something? Should my datasource/delegate be pointing to something? Can I give you more information? Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer with the two things you need to do, basically set them to point to your ViewController in StoryBoard and change your header file. Also, could you use NSLog in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to know it is actually called.

Comment: what do you mean by drag them to ViewController? As in one of my .h/.m files? I do not know where I need to drag to." @interface ViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> " Does not show up anywhere in my files. What is StoryBoard? Thank you for the help, sorry if I am being difficult I am very new to this.

Comment: In your CookViewController.h, make the top line, `@interface CookViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: Ok I did that know, but what about the StoryBoard and the dragging?

Comment: I edited viewDidLoad but still when I press the insert button the text in my field does not show its self on the UITableView.

Comment: In your CookViewController.h, do you have a property called `table`? And does it have a Solid Black Dot next to it?

Comment: Yes: IBOutlet UITableView *table;                   and there is a filled dot to left of it.

Comment: The UITables reference Outlet is table--Files owner

Comment: Hi does this solved your issue ? if yes just accept the answer @user1438042

Comment: No it didnt solve my question. Still nothing shows up in my tableview. that is why I am still asking questions @AalokParikh

Comment: @user1438042, could you github this project so I can pull and try and resolve your problem better? I'd love to do it via chat but your rep is not enough..

Comment: @vellvisher I dont have a github but I could some how send you my code and screenshots of my .XIB as well as any other information.

Comment: just send me your bundle at vellvisher@rediffmail.com if possible..i'll try to figure out what's wrong...